# addToCollection and set intermediate table column values as well

Tags: sails.js

I am using Sails v1.1 -

Following the example from the "Through" associations on sails - https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/through-associations

They defined a "through" association as basically a custom model. So this really isn't "through", it's just controlling the join table for the many to many relation.

So in the intermediate model, I added a custom attribute of `isTyping` seen below.

Is it possible to add to collection and set this intermediate value at same time?

For exmaple pseudocode with `setIntermediate`:

```
User.addToCollection(userId, 'pets', petId).setIntermediate('isTyping', true);
```

So following the example on the docs:

`myApp/api/models/User.js`

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    pets:{
      collection: 'pet',
      via: 'owner',
      through: 'petuser'
    }
  }
}
```

`myApp/api/models/Pet.js`

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    color: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    owners:{
      collection: 'user',
      via: 'pet',
      through: 'petuser'
    }
  }
}
```

`myApp/api/models/PetUser.js`

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    owner: {
      model:'user'
    },
    pet: {
      model: 'pet'
    },
    // I ADDED THIS INTERMEDIATE COLUMN NAME in the join table
    isTyping: {
      type: 'boolean',
      defaultsTo: false
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is right, but the way to do this is instead of using `Pet.addToCollection(petId, 'owners', userId)`/`User.addToCollection(userId, 'pets', petId)` or `Pet.removeFromCollection(petId, 'owners', userId)`/`User.removeFromCollection(userId, 'pets', petId)`, is to instead do:

```
PetUser.create({ owner: userId, pet: petId, isTyping: true }).populate('user').populate('pet')
```

I'm not sure if right, and this doesn't support the array argument that `addToCollection`/`removeFromCollection` does. And you also have to massage the data in order to get a list of `owners`/`pets` with the pivot attribute of `isTyping`.

Comment: As I see from the docs, you can access pivot attribute only by querying pivot model, so I can suggest you can't setup it without using pivot model itself. I don"t know for what reason you put it there, but IMHO it's better to put it in one of the related models. If you really need to have some data for link, maybe we need some method like `User.setPivotData(userId, 'pets', petId, someData); User.getPivotData(userId, 'pets', petId);`

Comment: The reason I put attribute on join table, is for each pet, the owner can be in "isFavorite" state. The user can mark certain pets as favorite. But he can't mark it favorite unless he is the owner of it. I seriously appreciate your discussions, it makes me think and then you respond with more thoughtful stuff! :)

Comment: Looks like your idea is about implementing [Eloquent pivot logic](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) for waterline, but as I see from sources there are no implemented methods for this. Maybe you can show your use case to Sails team and if they decided that this feature is missing, you can implement something similar. For example `User.findPivotRecord(user, 'pets', petId)` etc. TBH I also think these methods are missing in Waterline

Comment: Thanks Pavlo very much super appreciate it! I noticed also that they got the `many-through` relationship wrong in Waterline. They allow custom attributes, but `many-through` is distant relationship, not just custom model right?

Comment: I'm not sure but Waterline's `many-through` for me looks similar to [Eloquent has many trough](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

Comment: The Waterline many-through is actually like the Eloquent "Defining Custom Intermediate Table Models" on that same article. The `hasManyThrough` of Eloquent is for distant relations.