# Create unique multikey index via model settings

Tags: sails.js

I am using Sails v1.1 -

I created a many-to-many through custom model association following the sails doc here - https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/through-associations

The `PetUser` model has two columns `pet` and `user`, where each is the respective id. I want to create a unique multi-key index, meaning there cannot be two rows with the same combination of "pet and user". Meaning the second call should succeed, and third call should fail with uniqueness error:

```
await PetUser.create({ user: 1, pet: 33 }); // should succeed
await PetUser.create({ user: 1, pet: 44 }); // should succeed as user/pet combination is different
await PetUser.create({ user: 1, pet: 33 }); // should fail
```

I tried adding `unique: true` to both the `owner` and `pet` attribute on `PetUser` model below, but only the first `unique: true` gets respected.

So this is my code in `myApp/api/models/PetUser.js`

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    owner: {
      model:'user',
      unique: true
    },
    pet: {
      model: 'pet',
      unique: true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For implementing similar behavior I added a combined attribute and mark it unique. Also, I added `beforeCreate` and `beforeUpdate` model hooks on which I generate my combined attribute to check is it unique or not.

```
const YourModel = {

  attributes: {
    owner: {
      model: 'user',
    },
    pet: {
      model: 'pet',
    },
    petOwner: {
      type: 'string',
      unique: true,
    }
  },

  beforeCreate : function(values,cb) {
    // TODO get ids from related records or reset to default on missed relation record if you need it
    const petId = 35;
    const ownerId = 8;
    values.petOwner = `${petId}-${ownerId}`;
    cb();
  },

  beforeUpdate : function(values,cb) {
    YourModel.beforeCreate(values, cb)
  },
};

module.exports = YourModel;
```

In result when you tries to add the record with the same relations, you will get `E_UNIQUE` as you expected.

Comment: Thank you Pavlo very much for the attention you give my questions. This seems a workaround, I will use it if I can't figure it out. If i figure it out I will share with you. :) Or do you know for certain that it is not possible?

Comment: @Noitidart I just want to share my experience :) I guess it is a workaround. I haven't found a better solution in the limited time a half a year ago for a similar task, so this is on the prod on one of my projects on Sails.js :)

Comment: Thanks very much @Pavlo your experience is very valuable. It definitely definitely helps very much. What do you do for multiple `addToCollection`/`removeFromCollection`? We have to one by one `PetUser.create` right? Like here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53860856/1828637

Comment: @Noitidart frankly speaking I try to avoid relations in Waterline, but I really like it in Laravel Eloquent. When I tried to use `addToCollection` I did it only for one record at once. I haven't had a situation when I need to do it for multiple records on real project

Comment: Thanks Pavlo your comments are so valuble!! Do you know if `createEach` executes multiple `create`s? Or is it going to execute one statement?

Comment: I don't know. To figure it out usually I go to sources. I know this is waterline and method name is create each, so I need to go somewhere in waterline package and find createEach method declaration. When I open `node_modules/waterline` I see only `lib` folder looks appropriate. Inside I can see a folder `waterline` where is subfolder `methods` where I see `create-each.js`. So after checking this I found the line `node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/methods/create-each.js:292` where I can see that this query run it's one algorithm, but with multiple calls to adapter.